# Splunk regex matching for spring batch job times

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to write a regular expression to capture the job run times of a Spring Batch job but I am stuck. Below are a few examples of what the log for a spring batch job runtime could look like. I have also put down what I currently have but the regex I have is confused when the job may run for over a minute. Any help here would be appreciated. My end result i'm trying to get to is a panel in splunk that shows the average daily run time.

Also before anyone asks i have been using regex101 for the past couple days and still not getting good results. Figured stack community might be able to help!

Possible Job times formats:

```
709ms
59s709ms
1m59s709ms
```

My current query only works for the first two examples above. Also is there a way to get an expression where i don't need to put a number at the end of my capture group?

Current Regex Query:

```
(?<jobRunTimeMs1>\d*)ms?|(?<jobRunTimeS2>\d*)s?(?<jobRunTimeMs2>\d*)ms?|(?<jobRunTimeM3>\d*)m?(?<jobRunTimeS3>\d*)s?(?<jobRunTimeMs3>\d*)ms?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pull the extra question marks from your regex, it runs as [expected](https://regex101.com/r/OwXYaO/1):

```
| rex field=_raw "(?<jobRunTimeMs1>\d+)ms|(?<jobRunTimeS2>\d+)s(?<jobRunTimeMs2>\d+)ms|(?<jobRunTimeM3>\d+)m(?<jobRunTimeS3>\d+)s(?<jobRunTimeMs3>\d+)ms"
```

Append a couple [`coalesce`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval#Extended_Examples)s to bring them together, and drop the extraneous fields with [`fields`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fields):

```
| eval ms=coalesce(ms1,ms2,ms3), s=coalesce(s2,s3), m=m3
| fields - ms1 ms2 ms3 s2 s3 m3
```

However, I generally prefer to run sequential individual extractions (especially when the format may vary, as yours does) for readability (and not needing to do the `coalesce` step afterwards):

```
| rex field=_raw "(?<minutes>\d+)m\d"
| rex field=_raw "m?(?<seconds>\d+)s"
| rex field=_raw "s?(?<milliseconds>\d+)ms"
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually really love your suggestion on how you would do it for readability purposes!

Comment: @Trance339 - you may eventually want to update the sourcetype's props.conf to pull the fields without the manual steps, too :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need

```
(?:(?<jobRunTimeM3>\d+)m)?(?:(?<jobRunTimeS2>\d+)s)?(?<jobRunTimeMs2>\d+)ms?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TnQxYj/1). Here, the regex matches

- `(?:(?<jobRunTimeM3>\d+)m)?` - an optional one or more digits captured into `jobRunTimeM3` group and then an `m` char
- `(?:(?<jobRunTimeS2>\d+)s)?` - one or more digits captured into `jobRunTimeS2` group and then an `s` char
- `(?<jobRunTimeMs2>\d+)` - captures one or more digits into `jobRunTimeMs2` group and then matches
- `ms?` - `m` or `ms`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think i just liked Warrens way above to sequentially extract them. I am learning Splunk queries and that blew my mind i could do that. But thanks again!